# Does Intel QX6700 work asus p5g41-m motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, computer-building

Does Intel QX6700 work [Asus p5g41-m](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131399) motherboard?

Comment: It should work.

Comment: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5G41M_LX/HelpDesk_CPU/ doesn't list any QX http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-ASUS/P5G41-M.html lists some, but not that specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a little analysis of what CPUs are supported I can safety say that ASUS P5G41-M will support the `Intel® Core™2 Extreme Processor QX6700 (8M Cache, 2.66 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB)` because it supports `Intel® Core™2 Extreme Processor QX6800 (8M Cache, 2.93 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB)` the power requirements are identical and the `QX6800` was released after the `QX6700`.

You will have to verify your running the current revision of firmware of the BIOS before you perform the upgrade.  Officially its not on the list so there is chance the system won't boot for that reason.  If you want **guaranteed** support go for the `QX6800` instead.

You will have to verify the PCB is `1.00G` and the BIOS revision is `0304` before the new CPU will boot.